# JQuery toggle for multiple class element on click combining

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle, show-hide, togglebutton

as you can see. There are 3 show hide toggle on click.

```
<button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle">Hide</button>
<button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle">Show</button>

<button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle-2">Hide2</button>
<button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle-2">Two</button>

<button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle-3">Hide3</button>
<button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle-3">Three</button>

#btn-show {
    display: none;
}
```

My question, it's possible to make this code more simple by combining jquery toggle multi class, so if more toggle button needs to create, We no longer need to add new query anymore. Thanks.

```
$('.btn-toggle').on( 'click', function () {
 $('.btn-toggle').toggle();
});

$('.btn-toggle-2').on( 'click', function () {
 $('.btn-toggle-2').toggle();
});

$('.btn-toggle-3').on( 'click', function () {
 $('.btn-toggle-3').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each pair of buttons in a div.

HTML:

```
    <div class="tgl">
        <button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle">Hide</button>
        <button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle">Show</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tgl">
        <button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle">Hide2</button>
        <button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle">Two</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tgl">
        <button id="btn-hide" class="btn-toggle">Hide3</button>
        <button id="btn-show" class="btn-toggle">Three</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.btn-toggle').on( 'click', function () {
      $(this).parent().find('.btn-toggle').toggle();
    });
```

CSS:

```
#btn-show {
    display: none;
}
.tgl
{
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful and a fast answer, Thank you Sir.